# Getting query string from re written URL

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have url "SampleProject/profile/aA12". How can I get the value of the id from my rewritten URL using javascript? I want to get the "aA12" value.

Im using htaccess rewrite to rewrite my URL. Im new in rewritting url's. Any help will be appreciated. More powers and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

Try

```
'SampleProject/profile/aA12'.match(/\SampleProject\/profile\/(\w+)/)

'SampleProject/profile/aA12/xxx'.match(/\SampleProject\/profile\/(\w+)/)
```

'aA12' will be matched in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be quite a few ways to achieve your goal with JavaScript. A simple solution could be something like this:

```
let myURL = "SampleProject/profile/aA12";

let result = myURL.split('/').pop();
// returns "aA12"
```

The `.split('/')` method is dividing your string up into an array using the `/` character, and `.pop()` is simply returning the last element of that array.

Hope this helps! If you were looking for more advanced matching, i.e. if you wanted to ignore a potential query string on the end of the URL parameter, you could use regular expressions.

Comment: In my previous work im using this function "function getQueryStringValue(key) {  
        return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
      }" I dont know where to edit this to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a many way that you can use to achieve the desired method  i made you a code pen in this link

```
var url = "SampleProject/profile/aA12";

let res = url.split('/').pop();
console.log(res)
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQxNja

Comment: how to get the current url using javascript?